# How to solve the metadata wheel error during installation of pyqt5 with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, pyqt5, python-venv

I recently installed a virtual environement using pyvenv in Python and it worked fine until I needed to install PyQt5.

After that I also tried installing directly but it gave me other problems too related to SIP

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit,

I ran:

```
sudo -H python3 -m pip install pyqt5
```

The output was:

```
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.0.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpkqu84tmx
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-d7z8r80t/pyqt5
    Complete output (35 lines):
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    /usr/bin/qmake -query
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 131, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        config_settings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pn13k50g/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pn13k50g/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 82, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pn13k50g/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 477, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 62, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pn13k50g/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 86, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pn13k50g/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 223, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pn13k50g/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 76, in apply_user_defaults
        self._get_qt_configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pn13k50g/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 445, in _get_qt_configuration
        "v{0}".format(self.qt_version_str))
    sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpkqu84tmx Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: upgrade pip: `sudo -H python3 -m pip  --upgrade pip`

Comment: I already did it, and it didn't work in the latest version

Comment: There is no 32-bit version of PyQt5 available so you are installing compile that version, but your pip is very old.

Comment: It's version is 20.1.1

Comment: In this case, I cannot install PyQt5 anymore ?

Comment: mmm, my recommendation is that you download the source code and compile it manually, obviously for this you have to have Qt5 5.15 installed which can be a headache, have you tried to install an older version or use the pyqt5 that already comes with your ubuntu old?

Comment: at least it will be complicated because your pc is 32 bits and your ubuntu is very old, try installing pyqt5 from your system: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

Comment: I tried to use it but it always says ''''module not found'''

Comment: I can install, but when I call it, the code gives an error saying that the module was not found

Comment: Would it be because of the virtual environment that I am currently using ?

Comment: what is the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update && apt-cache search pyqt5`?

Comment: with apt-get it is installed in the python of the OS, and not from pyenv.